# Checkboxes not staying checked custom adapter

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a custom adapter for a listview. The listview has a checkbox, but the checkboxes are not staying checked when I scroll down and then scroll back up. I have a Model and in the model a boolean for 'selected'. Here is my adapter, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried multiple times and nothing seems to be working.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row_friends, null);

            CheckBox friend_checkbox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.friends_checkbox);


            if(data.get(position).selected) {
                friend_checkbox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                friend_checkbox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
CheckBox friend_checkbox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.friends_checkbox);
        friend_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                data.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
                Log.d("FriendAdapter", data.get(position).selected + "");
            }
        });
```

Comment: happens bcoz listview recycles views.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Raghunandan, this happens because the ListView recycles views, so convertView is probably not null most of the time. Try this instead :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row_friends, null);
    }
    CheckBox friend_checkbox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.friends_checkbox);
    friend_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            data.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
            Log.d("FriendAdapter", data.get(position).selected + "");
        }
    });
    if(data.get(position).selected) {
        friend_checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        friend_checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```